# Why does my pattern match on a collection fail in Scala?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

My code is as follows

```
  val hash = new HashMap[String, List[Any]]
  hash.put("test", List(1, true, 3))
  val result = hash.get("test")
  result match {
    case List(Int, Boolean, Int) => println("found")
    case _ => println("not found")
  }
```

I would expect "found" to be printed but "not found" is printed. I'm trying to match on any List that has three elements of type Int, Boolean, Int

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are checking for a list containing the companion objects [Int](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.Int$) and [Boolean](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.Boolean$). These are not the same as the classes [Int](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.Int) and [Boolean](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.Boolean).

Use a Typed Pattern instead.

```
val result: Option[List[Any]] = ...
result match {
  case Some(List(_: Int, _: Boolean, _: Int)) => println("found")
  case _                                      => println("not found")
}
```

[Scala Reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), Section 8.1 describes the different patterns you can use.

Answer (score 4):

The first problem is that the `get` method returns an `Option`:

```
scala>   val result = hash.get("test")
result: Option[List[Any]] = Some(List(1, true, 3))
```

So you'd need to match against `Some(List(...))`, not `List(...)`.

Next, you are checking if the list contains the *objects* `Int`, `Boolean` and `Int` again, not if it contains objects whose *types* are `Int`, `Boolean` and `Int` again.

`Int` and `Boolean` are both types and object companions. Consider:

```
scala> val x: Int = 5
x: Int = 5

scala> val x = Int
x: Int.type = object scala.Int

scala> val x: Int = Int
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int.type (with underlying type object Int)
 required: Int
       val x: Int = Int
                    ^
```

So the correct match statement would be:

```
case Some(List(_: Int, _: Boolean, _: Int)) => println("found")
```

Answer (score 3):

The following also works for Scala 2.8

```
List(1, true, 3) match {
  case List(a:Int, b:Boolean, c:Int) => println("found")
  case _ => println("not found")
}
```